# py2app - IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: python, error-handling, build, py2app

Getting the following error when trying to build my application. My code runs smoothly inside VScode (running the python file directly). I've looked online and I can't seem to find anyone who's had this error pop up. It used to happen to me when I wasn't in my virtual environment, but I definitely am now (`source venv/bin/activate`). What could it be? Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
    setup(
    ^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 153, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/distutils/dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 967, in run
    self._run()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1197, in _run
    self.run_normal()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1294, in run_normal
    self.process_recipes(mf, filters, flatpackages, loader_files)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/build_app.py", line 1143, in process_recipes
    rval = check(self, mf)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/recipes/detect_dunder_file.py", line 54, in check
    scan_bytecode_loads(names, node.code)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/recipes/detect_dunder_file.py", line 31, in scan_bytecode_loads
    scan_bytecode_loads(names, c)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/wiggly/Desktop/twitterBot/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/py2app/recipes/detect_dunder_file.py", line 25, in scan_bytecode_loads
    name = co.co_names[inst.arg]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I use the default setup.py using the command provided in the docs `py2applet --make-setup bot.py`

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ["bot.py"]
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={"py2app": OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=["py2app"],
)
```

Comment: Would you please add also the dependency versions you're using? `pip freeze` would list that for you

Comment: Also, a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is going to be valuable for other users to find a good answer for you.

Comment: @lepsch py2app==0.28.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have installed a beta version of Python (version `3.11`). And looks like `py2app` version `0.28.2` is not compatible with it. Try to uninstall the `3.11` version and [install the current release version `3.10`](https://www.python.org/downloads/macos/) and it should work. Also, recreate the virtual environment after you install it because the current one would still be pointing to the `3.11` version.

Comment: I copied the files over to another folder, then created another virtual environment and imported the requirements.txt file. But when I execute ```pip install -r requirements.txt``` from the venv, it gives me "Requirement already satisfied" even though the packages are not actually in the venv. My program also doesn't run as it can't find the modules necessary for it to run. I've also tried ```pip install --target=/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/site-packages tweepy``` as well as with ```--upgrade``` and still not working.

Comment: It should install a new one if the new virtual env is activated, otherwise, it's going to install system-wise. And that's probably what's going on. Did you actually activate the virtual env with the `activate` command? The command is `. venv_name/bin/activate` for Linux/macOS (notice the dot in front of it) and `venv_name/Scripts/activate.bat` for Windows. BTW, to create a virtual env you can use just `python3 -m venv venv_name` and it should create the `venv_name` folder for you. And to deactivate a virtual env just do `deactivate`.

Comment: Yes, I've done exactly that. I've uninstall 3.11 and installed 3.10.5 and in the errors when trying to execute ```python setup.py py2app```, the new venv still shows up as 3.11... On macOS, to uninstall an app, you usually simply drag-and-drop the application in the bin, but i guess that doesn't work very well with Python...

Comment: Can you open another terminal window and test again? If you've kept the terminal open while installing it could be still pointing to the old one. BTW, to uninstall it just go to Applications and drag and drop the `Python 3.11` folder into the trash bin. And don't forget to recreate the virtual env again.

Comment: Same result. I think I have to delete more files than just drag-and-drop. I don't see another way. But the problem is that I don't know what to delete and what not to delete.

Comment: I got it! I had to delete the Python.framework folder (under Library/Frameworks) as well as all the steps you've mentioned. 

Thanks a whole lot!!!